# Keyword classification in Scala... simple?

Tags: scala

I am pretty newbie in Scala, my background expertise is basically Java and Python, and I'd like to know your thoughts about this code snippet written in Scala to know if this is a "regular piece of code written in Scala" or if this is something kind of "obfuscated" and overcomplicated.

The code just implements a simple decision flow to categorize keywords depending on a few rules.

Thanks!

```
def preprocess(kwd: Keyword): Option[PrepKeyword] = {

val isFoo = kwd.name.exists(_.toLowerCase(locale) == "foo")
    for {
      filterCategory <- (isFoo, kwd.type) match {
                case (true, _)  => Some(false)
                case (false, 1) => Some(true)
                case (false, 2) => Some(false)
                case _          => None
              }
      fooName <- kwd.name match {
                        case None | Some("name1")                           => None
                        case Some("myCategory") if filterCategory           => Some("GreatCategory")
                        case other                                          => other
                      }
    } yield PrepKeyword(
      keyword = kwd,
      name = fooName,
      path = if (isFoo) "Foo1" else "Foo2"
    )
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 1):

The posted code won't compile without a working definition of `Keyword` and `PrepKeyword`. And `type` is a reserved word so `kwd.type` isn't allowed (might be version dependent).

The code, as presented, is inconsistent or just plain wrong in its indenting but, other than that, it's reasonably clear in intent and presentation.

The logic is, perhaps, overly convoluted. I found that I had to go back and forth to see how output was built from input. I eventually decided that `kwd.name` was the key value from which most everything else flows. With that in mind I tried to rebuild the logic.

```
def preprocess(kwd: Keyword): Option[PrepKeyword] = {
  val fooName = "(?i)(foo)".r
  kwd.name.flatMap{
    case "name1"      => None
    case "myCategory" =>
      kwd.typ match {
        case 1 => Some(PrepKeyword(kwd, "GreatCategory", "Foo2"))
        case 2 => Some(PrepKeyword(kwd, "myCategory", "Foo2"))
        case _ => None
      }
    case fooName(fnm) => Some(PrepKeyword(kwd, fnm, "Foo1"))
    case nonFoo       => Some(PrepKeyword(kwd, nonFoo, "Foo2"))
  }
}
```

This, according to my tests so far, produces the same results. It builds the output in multiple places but in each case it's pretty easy to see how the input directed the output.

Answer (score 0):

Overall in terms of style it looks fine to me. The usage of a for comprehension with `Option` is pretty idiomatic, so I wouldn't call it obfuscated or overcomplicated.

That being said I do think the logic could be flattened out a bit to make it clearer to the reader which inputs of `Keyword` to `preprocess` will result in a `Some(PrepKeyword(_))`.

```scala
case class Keyword(
  name: Option[String],
  typeCode: Int
)

case class PrepKeyword(
  keyword: Keyword,
  name: String,
  path: String
)

def preprocess(kwd: Keyword): Option[PrepKeyword] = {
  val isFoo = kwd.name.exists(_.toLowerCase() == "foo")
  val maybeFilterCategory: Option[Boolean] = {
    (isFoo, kwd.typeCode) match {
      case (true, _) => Some(false)
      case (false, 1) => Some(true)
      case (false, 2) => Some(false)
      case _ => None
    }
  }
  
  (kwd.name, maybeFilterCategory) match {
    case (Some(name), Some(filterCategory)) if name != "name1" => {
      val fooName = if (filterCategory && name == "myCategory") {
        "GreatCategory"
      } else {
        name
      }
      val path = if (isFoo) "Foo1" else "Foo2"
      
      Some(PrepKeyword(kwd, fooName, path))
    }
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

In the above refactor, it's easier to see that in order to return a `Some(PrepKeyword(_))`, as a minimum requirement the `Option`s `kwd.name` and `maybeFilterCategory` must both be `Some(_)`.

Note: `type` is a reserved word in Scala so it can't be used as an identifier. You can use backticks as an alternative, e.g.

```scala
case class Keyword(
  name: Option[String],
  `type`: Int
)
```

but I personally find this kind of ugly, so in the refactor I used `typeCode` instead.